# Issue with inserting data from CSV

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, freeze

I have an issue with Importing CSV into database to be more precise, I generate CSV file from TXT file and then i try to import it into Database. Appplication hangs on function that should INSERT data into the table. I tried various options to do this even without csv file just by sending test data directly.
What have i done wrong here or what am I missing?

```
 //Uruchomienie importu z CSV do tabeli
private void Loading_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    DataTable zaimportowane = WezDane();
    if (zaimportowane == null) return;
    ZapiszDane(zaimportowane);
    MessageBox.Show("load data succ.......!","LoadingDB");
    NazwaCSV.Text = null;
    Cursor = Cursors.Default;

}
//Tutaj ładują się dane po zaimportowaniu pliku CSV
private DataTable WezDane()
{

    DataTable zaimportowane = new DataTable();

    try
    {

        using(StreamReader odczyt = new StreamReader(NazwaCSV.Text))
        {

            string naglowek = odczyt.ReadLine();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(naglowek))
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Brak danych nagłówka", "DataTableDB");
                return null;

            }

            string[] Kolumny = naglowek.Split(';');
            foreach(string Kolumna in Kolumny)
            {

                zaimportowane.Columns.Add(Kolumna);

            }

            while (!odczyt.EndOfStream)
            {

                string linia = odczyt.ReadLine();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(linia)) continue;
                string[] pola = linia.Split(';');
                DataRow zaimportowanyWiersz = zaimportowane.NewRow();

                for(int i = 0;i< pola.Count(); i++)
                {

                    zaimportowanyWiersz[i] = pola[i];

                }

                zaimportowane.Rows.Add(zaimportowanyWiersz);

            }

        }

    }
    catch
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Problem z odczytem pliku :(", "DataTableDB");

    }

    return zaimportowane;

}
//Wpis danych do tabeli
private void ZapiszDane(DataTable zaimportowane_dane)
{

    using (conn)
    {

        conn.Open();
        foreach ( DataRow zaimportowanyWiersz in zaimportowane_dane.Rows)
        {

            SqlCommand SQLcomm = new SqlCommand(@"insert into 
                wyscig(INDEX,TAG ID,TAG COUNT,DATE,READ ON ANT)" +
                @"values ("+zaimportowane_dane.Columns[0]+
                ","+zaimportowane_dane.Columns[1]+
                ","+zaimportowane_dane.Columns[2]+
                ","+zaimportowane_dane.Columns[3]+
                ","+zaimportowane_dane.Columns[4]+")");
            SQLcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue(zaimportowane_dane.Columns[0].Equals("INDEX").ToString(), "TEST");
            SQLcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue(zaimportowane_dane.Columns[1].Equals("TAG ID").ToString(), "TEST");
            SQLcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue(zaimportowane_dane.Columns[2].Equals("TAG COUNT").ToString(), "TEST");
            SQLcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue(zaimportowane_dane.Columns[3].Equals("DATE").ToString(), "TEST");
            SQLcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue(zaimportowane_dane.Columns[4].Equals("READ ON ANT").ToString(), "TEST");
            SQLcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It's very hard to tell what the issue might be from just the code, have you not debugged and stepped through it while importing the CSV?  That will help enormously in seeing whether the issue is a simple SQL connection error, or a more complex code related problem.

Comment: I tried to use breakpoints but it doesn't work as well ;.; I will post soon simplified option that works , a colleague from work finally had some time to look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an answer, I needed to change as well fields in table because of their naming and it looks like I made it harder than it was needed to

```
 conn.Open();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(NazwaCSV.Text))
        {
            reader.ReadLine();
            string line;
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                line = reader.ReadLine();
                string[] pola = line.Split(';');
                using (SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    sc.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Wyscig(Pozycja,nrTAG,cTAG,czas,dat) VALUES (@poz,@tagid,@tagcount,@data,@odczyt)";
                    sc.Connection = conn;
                    sc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@poz", pola[0]));
                    sc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tagid", pola[1]));
                    sc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tagcount", pola[2]));
                    sc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data", pola[3]));
                    sc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@odczyt", pola[4]));
                    sc.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }

            }
        }
        conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things to try:

- Extract your INSERT statement with the values and try running that against your database to ensure it works at that level (checks syntax and/or any locking issues)
- You appear to be closing your connection within the for loop, trying moving it.